# Demonstration of equivalence

Tags: logic

I have this assignment:

> Show the following (DO NOT USE TRUTH TABLES, Truth tables are not allowed):

Of course, I have checked the equivalence between the following expressions with a truth table:

$P \leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)$

I started first from the right expression, but I was not finding a connection between both, so I decided to elaborate the left expression:

$(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow P)$ % biconditional

$(\neg P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor P)$ % conditionals

$(\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land P) \lor (Q \land \neg Q) \lor (Q \land P)$ % 2 contradictions are ignored because of $\lor$=ORs

$(\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (Q \land P)$ % which is the same thing of the right side expression

Is this a demonstration? Am I correct?

Comment: $\checkmark$ You're on the right track. Each step is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\checkmark$  You're on the right track. Each step is correct. I'd write the justifications something like this:
$\begin{align}\\[1ex]\because
(P \leftrightarrow Q)
\equiv &(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow P) & \text{by definition of biconditional}
\\[1ex]
\equiv &(\neg P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor P) & \text{by conditional equivalence}
\\[1ex]
\equiv &(\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land P) \lor (Q \land \neg Q) \lor (Q \land P)
& \text{by distribution}
\\[1ex]
\equiv &(\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (\bot) \lor (\bot) \lor (Q \land P)
& \text{by contradiction}
\\[1ex]
\equiv &(\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (Q \land P)
& \text{by disjunction identity}
\\[3ex]
\therefore (P\leftrightarrow Q) \equiv & (\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (Q \land P) &{\cal Q.E.D.} 
\end{align}$

The "by contradiction" step can be skipped (as you did), but in a formal proof it doesn't hurt to include even the blatantly obvious.